# Virtualization and Clipboard Sharing

Tags: windows, linux, virtualization, virtual-machine

Hey all,
I was wondering how does clipboard-sharing work when using a hosted virtualized OS.
I mean, how would I go about writing such a bridge, for say a Windows host running a Linux guest?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this only works when the "guest drivers / additions" are installed which enabled the host to communicate with the guest. I guess it's possible for the host to peek into guest memory and get the clipboard but that'd probably be much, much harder than a guest driver.

If you're not using a virtualization package that offers an SDK I think you'll be in for quite a task hacking from host to guest to peek into memory and processes.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, no such drivers are currently available for the distro involved (Slitaz) - So I'm planning on writing one.

Comment: Currently, the quickest and dirtiest solution, seems to be running a  client/server process on each machine - communicating through the LAN. Now I only need to hook into the Windows clipboard calls (done this before), as well as the Linux ones (haven't done so before...).